# Is there a difference between Boost's scoped mutex and WinAPi's critical section?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex, critical-section

In Windows environment, is Boost's scoped mutex using WinAPI's critical sections, or something else?

Comment: You didn't take a look into the Boost source code, did you? :)

Comment: I'm in a location where I have no access to it :(

Comment: You need Internet access for both Stack Overflow and Boost sources. http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The current version of `boost::mutex` uses neither a Win32 `CRITICAL_SECTION`, nor a Win32 Mutex. Instead, it uses atomic operations and a Win32 Event for blocking waits.

Older versions (boost 1.34.1 and prior) were a wrapper around `CRITICAL_SECTION` on Windows.

Incidentally, the mutex itself is not scoped. The `boost::mutex::scoped_lock` type and, in recent versions, `boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex>` and `boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>` provide RAII wrappers for locking a mutex to ensure you don't forget to unlock it.

The `boost::lock_guard<>` and `boost::unique_lock<>` templates work with any type with `lock()` and `unlock()` member functions, so you can use them with inter-process mutexes if desired.

Comment: This is probably almost / just as efficient as a Win32 Critical Section?

Comment: @unixman83: I doubt it, a critical section is fast because it is in-process only, you can't use it between processes. It isn't a kernel object, but Win32 Events are. So I would assume this isn't as fast as a CS.

Comment: @gbjbaanb Have you timed it? Note that `boost::mutex` only resorts to using the event if there is contention --- the "fast path" uses atomic ops only.

Comment: by "Win32 Event for blocking waits" do mean WaitForSingleObject function ?

Comment: @Guillaume07: Yes, it uses `WaitForSingleObject` on a win32 event (created with `CreateEvent`) when doing a blocking wait.

Answer (score 3):

Win32's CRITICAL_SECTION can only be used among the threads of *a single process*. If you need to use something between processes, you need a mutex. Boost says nothing about critical sections so I would assume it is using mutexes.

"scoped" just means it has a wrapper that uses [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to automatically unlock the mutex at the end of a particular scope.

Comment: Yes, these I already knew. Hmm, guess I need to look into the actual source later on..

Comment: If they call it a "mutex", and do not mention the phrase "critical section" assume with very high probability it is not a critical section.

Comment: Boost::interprocess is reputable enough that I think that way about it. Clarity is important. If it were someone's independent library I'm not sure I'd be as confident.

Comment: However, the docs for Boost::mutex clearly say "These are all thread-level mutexes; interprocess mutexes are not supported".

Comment: WTF? OP says nothing about the particular type of mutex, only asked about scoping. There is interprocess_mutex and named_mutex. Try reading the docs yourself. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes.mutexes_interprocess_mutexes

Comment: The original poster asked about a mutex in Boost, so it's natural to assume this refers to Boost::mutex rather than some more specific mutex. This is part of the thread library rather than the interprocess library, and in the past did accordingly map to a critical section on Win32 rather than an OS-level mutex. Thus "I would assume it is using mutexes" is a reasonable assumption but a false one in this case. Even if the OP meant a different kind of mutex, this fact means that the general assumption does not apply universally.

Comment: :shrug: I don't see why it's more natural to assume the Boost::thread library than the Boost::interprocess library... but whatever.