# Creating a mutex like program using CriticalSection

Tags: c++, synchronization, mutex, critical-section

e.g.

```
EnterCriticalSection ( cs );
LeaveCriticalSection ( cs );
```

I want to create a function locking it and release if invoke your function call or leave the object.

How can get started to work out the class?

Answer (score 2):

So a scoped CriticalSection?

```
class ScopedCriticalSection {
   CRITICAL_SECTION cs;

   ScopedCriticalSection()
   {
      if (!InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount(&cs, 0x00000400))
         throw std::runtime_error("Could not initialise CriticalSection object");
      EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
   }

   ~ScopedCriticalSection()
   {
      LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
      DeleteCriticalSection(&cs);
   }
};

void foo()
{
   ScopedCriticalSection scs;

   /* code! */
}
```

Or [consider a Boost mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877577/is-there-a-difference-between-boosts-scoped-mutex-and-winapis-critical-section).

Comment: Your constructor take a `LPCRITICAL_SECTION` as argument, that is missing in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the critical section in a `Mutex` class with public functions `acquire` and `release` and have a second class called `ScopedLock` acquire the mutex on construction and release it on destruction.

The Mutex:

```
class Mutex {
   public:
     Mutex() {
       //TODO: create cs
     }
     ~Mutex() {
       //TODO: destroy cs
     }
     void acquire() {
       EnterCriticalSection(cs);
     }
     void release() {
       LeaveCriticalSection(cs);
     }
   private:
     LPCRITICAL_SECTION cs;
     Mutex(const Mutex&); //non-copyable
     Mutex& operator=(const Mutex&); //non-assignable
};
```

The Lock:

```
class ScopedLock {
  public:
    ScopedLock(Mutex* mutex_) : mutex(mutex_) {
      mutex->acquire();
    }
    ~ScopedLock() {
      mutex->release();
    }
  private:
    Mutex* mutex;
};
```

Use it like this:

```
Mutex someMutex;

void foo() {
  ScopedLock lock(&someMutex);
  //critical stuff here
}

void bar() {
  ScopedLock lock(&someMutex);
  //other critical stuff here
}
```