# Cost of mutex,critical section etc on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, mutex, critical-section

I read somewhere that the overhead of a mutex is not that much, because the context switching only happens in case of contention.

Also known Futexes in Linux.

Does the same thing hold good in Windows? Is Critical Section a more apt map to mutexes in Linux.

From what i gathered, Critical Sections provide better optimal performance compared to Mutex, is this true for every case?

Is there a corner case where mutexes are faster than critical section in Windows.

Assume only a single process-threads are accessing the mutexes(Just to eliminate the other benefit of Critical Sections)

Added Info: OS windows Server,
             Language C++

Comment: Of course, if your application has frequent contention, you may rethink the idea that mutexes don't have much overhead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Considering the specific purpose of `Critical Sections` and `Mutexes` I don't think you can ask a question regarding the cost as you don't have much alternative when you need multiple threads touching the same data. Obviously, if you just need to increment/decrement a number, you can use the `Interlocked*()` functions on a `volatile` number and you're good to go. But for anything more complex, you need to use a synchronization object.

Start your reading here on the [Synchronization Objects available on Windows^](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360.aspx). All functions are listed there, nicely grouped and properly explained. *Some are Windows 8 only.*

**As regarding your question, `Critical Sections` are less expensive than `Mutexe`s as they are designed to operate in the same process.** Read [this^](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105678) and [this^](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682530.aspx) or just the following quote.

> A critical section object provides synchronization similar to that provided by a mutex object, except that a critical section can be used only by the threads of a single process. Event, mutex, and semaphore objects can also be used in a single-process application, but critical section objects provide a slightly faster, more efficient mechanism for mutual-exclusion synchronization (a processor-specific test and set instruction). Like a mutex object, a critical section object can be owned by only one thread at a time, which makes it useful for protecting a shared resource from simultaneous access. Unlike a mutex object, there is no way to tell whether a critical section has been abandoned.

**I use `Critical Sections` for same process synchronization and `Mutexes` for cross-process synchronization.** *Only when I REALLY need to know if a synchronization object was abandoned, I use Mutexes in the same process.*

***So, if you need a sync object, the question is not what are the costs but which is cheaper :) There's really no alternative but memory corruption.***

**PS**: There might be alternatives like the [one mentioned in the selected answer here^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877577/is-there-a-difference-between-boosts-scoped-mutex-and-winapis-critical-section) but I always go for core platform-specific functionality vs. cross-platformness. It's always faster! *So if you use Windows, use the tools of Windows :)*

**UPDATE**

Based on your needs, you might be able to reduce the need of sync objects by trying to do as much self-contained work in a thread as possible and only combine the data at the end or every now and then.

**Stupid Example**: *Take a list of URLs. You need to scrape them and analyze them.*

1. Throw in a bunch of threads and start picking URLs, one by one, from the input list. For each one your process you centralize the results as you do it. It's real time and cool
2. Or you can throw in the threads each of them having a slice of the input URLs. This removes the need to sync the selection process. You store the analysis result in the thread and at the end, you combine the result just once. Or just once every 10 URLs let's say. Not for each of them. This will reduce the sync operations dramatically.

**So costs can be lowered by choosing the right tool and thinking how to lower the lock and unlocks. But costs cannot be removed :)**

**PS**: I only think in URLs :)

**UPDATE 2:**

Had the need in a project to do some measuring. And the results were quite surprising:

- A **`std::mutex`** is most expensive. *(price of cross-platformness)*
- A **Windows native `Mutex`** is 2x faster than `std`.
- A **`Critical Section`** is 2x faster than the **native `Mutex`**.
- A **`SlimReadWriteLock`** is +-10% of the **`Critical Section`**.
- My homemade **`InterlockedMutex` (spinlock)** is 1.25x - 1.75x faster than the **`Critical Section`**.

Comment: I knew i could not remove the cost, but was just thinking whether critical section or mutexes are ideal for me. Thanks for the info though

Comment: -1 for the volatile.  You should never rely on volatile alone for threading. Either use atomic, or combine volatile with memory fences. Else, your volatile access can end up reordered on Linux / gcc, for example.

Comment: That's not true that there is no other choice. Windows implementation is system-wide and governed by permissions\acess lists, mutexes are meant to be sync interfaces between processes, they are not equivalent of classic mutex. Critical sections interface with thread priority manager, threads in Windows have own memory area - Thread Local Storage. The calls to those functions involve quite a number of dll calls.  If deep and pervasive interaction with OS not required, one may use non-API, user-space mutexes, spinlocks, atomics, etc. for performance's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Using std::mutex on windows 8 I usually get 3-4x improvement (on non contending case) speedup by using my own custom made spin lock:

**mutex based**

```
auto time = TimeIt([&]() {
for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
    bool val = mutex.try_lock();
    if (val) {
        data.value = 1;
    }
}
```

});

**home made lock free**

```
time = TimeIt([&]() {
    for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++) {
        if (!guard.exchange(true)) {
            // I own you
            data.value = 1;
            guard.store(true);
        }
    }
});
```

Tests are made on x86.

I haven't figured out what std::mutex uses underline on windows because it generates a lot of code.