# Is it possible to implement C++11 mutex concept for use by std::condition_variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, mutex, condition-variable

I find that the `std::mutex` implementation in Visual Studio 2013 is too slow. It uses a heavy weight mutex to assure that synchronization can be achieved even between processes which is all fine and dandy; Unless you're not talking to other processes and could really use that extra speed that `CRITICAL_SECTION` with it's spin-lock offers on Win32.

I tried to implement a `fast_recursive_mutex` that adheres to the C++11 mutex concept and that fulfills all obligations according to spec. In all senses, it's a drop-in replacement for `std::mutex` as long as you're not synchronizing between processes.

It works great with `std::lock_guard` and `std::unique_lock`. However I encounter problems when trying to use it with `std::condition_variable` because `std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&)` doesn't admit my `fast_recursive_mutex` due to the hard coded use of `std::mutex`.

So my questions are:

1. Why does `wait()` not admit another mutex type than `std::mutex`?
2. Is there something I can do about it? (Short of re-implementing condition_variable).

Comment: The first question of "why does it not admit another type", you may as well be asking why did they write two different `condition_variable` classes and not simply have one type with a templated mutex type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`std::condition_variable_any`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable_any/) for any *lockable type*.

Comment: Do you have any idea regarding the first question?

Comment: @anderas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758353/whats-the-difference-between-stdcondition-variable-and-stdcondition-variable

Comment: I can't believe I missed this both when I looked at the references and when googling... Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I believe `std::mutex` implementation in Visual Studio 2012/2013 already uses critical sections. Just check `VSDIR\VC\crt\thr\mutex.c`

You can also empirically check this using `std::mutex::native_handle()` method and cast what's returned to `CRITICAL_SECTION`.

Comment: Many people have measured this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18092273/2498188 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/24470878/2498188 here for example. My own measurements agree with these..

Comment: My point was VS doesn't literally use heavy weight ipc-capable mutexes but rather `Concurrency::critical_section` that somehow (check `critical_section::_Acquire_lock()` in VC\crt\src\rtlocks.cpp) is slower twice than `CRITICAL_SECTION`.